# Is is possible to add a bespoke Twig template loader?

Tags: templating, twigextension

Twig lets you provide alternate (or multiple) template loaders. I'd like to take advantage of this to do use a bespoke loader to pull in components from a pattern library using a shorthand syntax like `{% include '*mycomponent' %}` or similar.

Does Craft expose the environment used for loading templates in a way that I can append/overwrite the default filesystem loader with my own custom implementation?

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call Craft's [`TemplatesService->getTwig()`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/TemplatesService#getTwig-detail)  (`craft()->templates->getTwig()`), the first parameter you can pass in is your custom template loader classname.

i.e. `craft()->templates->getTwig('\My\Awesome\Plugin\TemplateLoader, array('my' => 'options')`

Comment: Many thanks @brad that is exactly what I was looking for! Top stuff.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing as Mark, but am struggling to see how this fits into the plugin architecture. What do I need to do with the returned Twig Environment in order to render a template with my custom template loader attached?

Comment: @brad-bell this doesn't look possible in Craft3?